# Is there a way to change value while debugging a Flutter App

Tags: flutter, debugging

As in all languages Debugging is a core concept as we all need to do it:)
I am trying to edit and set a value while running a Flutter App in **debug Mode**.
However i could not find any place where i can **edit the value and set it** to test the effect of the change in the flow.

- In VS Code i have put breakpoints and run the app in the debug mode.
  Set watchpoints etc.. but could not find a way to edit  a value?

İs this possible in flutter apps?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is possible. In Visual Studio Code there would be a `Set Value` command on the context menu if you clicked on any variable which you can change, but it is not available when debugging a Flutter application. Even if you go to `Debug Console` when paused on a breakpoint, and assign a new value to a variable there, it is not reflected when you resume running your code.

Comment: Thanks Peter
Thats  a shame, this is such a useful thing while debugging.
Theres dart developer tools with lots of features but no **set value**

Comment: @solen-dogan please let me know if you found any work around

Answer (score 0):

I would love this functionality too.

I opened an Feature request on Flutter's github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105250

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to be able to change variable values on debug mode in a tricky way.

The idea is to execute a method that changes de value from the debugger.

```
String variableToChange = 'test';
final changeVariableValue = (String value) => variableToChange = value;
final debbugPointer = null;
```

In order to make it your you should add the debugger marker in the third line.
Then on the debuuger screen once stoped execute:

```
changeValue('your new value);
```

You will see varible has changed on VSCode debuger.

[image: Executing command]

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if (kDebugMode)
  doSomething();
```